# Can I draft an Gmail message in Google Docs

Tags: gmail, google-docs

I'm looking to create a draft email collaboratively with multiple people and not risk hitting send by accident.

Is there a special doc type in Google Docs for email templates?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, according to [**Draft Emails from Google Docs**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/11930385):

1. Create a new [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/).
2. From the menu, select `Insert` > `Building blocks` > `Email draft`

   [image: Insert > Building blocks > Email draft.]

   Alternatively, you can also type `@email` in the doc and select from autocomplete menu

   [image: email autocomplete]
3. Update the subject, body, and add any contacts with `@` symbol
4. You can open the email in Gmail by clicking the [image: M] on the top left

   [image: Preview in Gmail]